# How to use different icon libraries in React Native?

Tags: react-native, icons

Good afternoon everyone.

I specify the exact library in beginning of my code

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

I have a quesiton on how to use different vector libraries together. For example >>

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
      let iconName;

      if (route.name === 'Dashboard') {
        iconName = 'dashboard';
      } else if (route.name === 'Trades') {
        iconName = 'compare-arrows';
      }

      // You can return any component that you like here!
      return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
    },
  })}
>
```

As you can see here for `Dashboard` I use `iconName = 'dashboard';` from FontAwesome library.

But what I suppose to do if I want to add icon for `Trades` from another library, let's say from `AntDesign`? How I can specify for every element different icon libraries? If I wish add even more Icons from another different libraries?

Shortly: How I can add multiple icon libraries and use icons from them together.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of my gist from here

https://gist.github.com/saachitech/02633cb443e121b4a792c537cdedc385

You can use it like

```
Import Fonticon from “./fontIcon”;

<Fonticon type={“FontAwesome”} name={“some name”} size={10} color={“#FFF”} />
```

`type` could be anything from vector icons library.